# Why is a Module Not found error happening despite having the init file?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using Spyder with Python 3.8 in Anaconda. I have files p,c,s,d and init in the same directory. I am posting the relevant lines.

File p:

`from s import C`

File s:

```
class S():
from d import D
```

File c:

```
from .s import S
class C(S):
```

File d:

`class D()`

init file:

```
from .s import S
from .c import C
from .d import D
```

File p is the main file here. When I run it, I get a module not found error. with the traceback being

```
from s import C (file P)
from .s import S (init)
class S() (file s)
from d import  D (file s)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named d.
Why is this happening? I am using a Mac.

Comment: There is some missing info. Can you post the whole project struct?

Comment: So your file names are `A` and `B`, and your module names are `.a` and `.b`? Your question and your code imply two different things.

Comment: My bad, should have added more info. Files A and B contain classes A and B.

Comment: Shouldn't it be files `a` and `b`? Please post a minimal project structure tree in the question: make mention to `__ init __` files, where your imports are defined and what you're running/calling.

Comment: Looks like I did not give complete information. I will add more to make it relevant.

Comment: Added relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a package `mypackage´,

```
mypackage/
  __init__.py
  a.py
  b.py
```

and `mypackage/__init__.py` is

```
from .a import A
from .b import B
```

(but that doesn't really matter here)
then `mypackage/b.py` can import `A` via a relative import

```
from .a import A
```

or an absolute import

```
from mypackage.a import A
```

but **not**

```
from a import A
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I apologize for how I initially wrote the question.